# Help with LINQ to DataTable query

Tags: c#, linq, dataset

I've successfully used OLEDB to import an excel file to a datatable and display it in a data grid view. Now I want to use LINQ and set the datasource for the grid as the LINQ query, however it is not working. Here is the full code:

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\Pricing2.xlsx" + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;ImportMixedTypes=Text;TypeGuessRows=0""";

OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand
(
    "SELECT * FROM [Pricing$]",conn
);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
adapter.Fill(dt);
var query = from a in dt.AsEnumerable()
            select a;
dataGridView1.DataSource = query;
```

Comment: Why not `dataGridview1.DataSource = dt;`? LINQ is not used for this.

Comment: @Danny: I assume that he's testing for a more complicated query.

Comment: I'm inserting pieces of the datatable results into my database. I use LINQ to SQL as ADO.NET and manually making/accessing stored procs is a waste of time.

Comment: I know it's not, what I posted on here was just code to test the output of the data collected through the excel file. Above I was explaining what I intended to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databinding works with `IList`s, not `IEnumerable`s.

In order to bind to a LINQ query, you need to call `ToList()`.
To bind to a LINQ-to-DataTable query (a LINQ query that returns `DataRow`s), [you need to call `AsDataView()` instead](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/01/binding-to-lists-of-datarows.html).
This returns an `ITypedList` implementation that will show properties for the columns in the table.

If you select an anonymous type (not a `DataRow`), you just need `ToList()`.

Comment: .Tolist() came up with some very strange results, i forgot about .CopyToDataTable()

Answer (score 0):

`.ToList()` will not work, `.CopyToDataTable()` is the correct call.

Comment: This works to, I don't know if you edited your post to include that or you already had it, but if it is the latter I saw ToList() immediately and didn't read the rest :(

Comment: I wrote a [blog post](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/01/binding-to-lists-of-datarows.html) with a more thorough explanation.